# sign in as different user empty page

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, login

I have added my test user by using powershell to Reader group (New-SPUser) When I try "Sign in as different user" the login dialog pops up three time and then it will be an empty page nothing no access denied and no error.

Comment: try adding the user manually to a different site and logging in as that user, just to eliminate if there is an issue with the test account.

Comment: I added the user manually to another site still same problem.

Answer (score 0):

You probably added a wrong user or password, and after 3 times trying a wrong psw or user name it will redirect you to nothing.

Check if your powershell script was correct, with user name and psw check if the domain name when you try to login is correct.

Verify the user in the active directory.

I'm sure something wrong with the user.

btw, you only get "access deinied", when the user exists and it doesn't have access to a paticular site.

Comment: I tried to add the user by going to Site Actions -> site permission and add the user directly to the group. still geting same thing empty page and nothing in ULS logs. It is my dev environment and domain is right. I checked the user in AD it was ok.

Comment: try to execute the synchronization timer jobs in the central admin. I'm sure there is something wrong with the user either the name or psw is uncorrect. Because if i try to log in myself to my SHarePoint and i add 3 times wrong psw, im redirected to empty page and nothing happens.